# mu4e with elpaca

Tags: package, mu4e

I'm trying to use elpaca package manager, so far so good except for mu4e which does not install (or launch). My code is the following:

```
(use-package mu4e
          :elpaca (mu4e :host github
                    :repo "djcb/mu"
                    :files ("mu4e/*.el")
                    :pre-build (("./autogen.sh") ("ninja" "-C" "build"))))
          :commands (mu4e)
          :bind (([f5] . mu4e))
          :config
;;        ...)
```

f5 is undefined, and M-x mu4e results in "Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, mu4e-config".
Any idea on how to set up mu4e with elpaca? Thanks!